# How to remove subsets from a string in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have the following type of text:

```
dbt とは何をするツールなのか？2022.02.09data build tool|dbt|Tech|こんにちは、ソフトウェアエンジニアの冨田です。
```

I want to remove all the YYYY.MM.DD occurrences all the way through 'Tech|' included.

So I want the final string to look like this:

```
dbt とは何をするツールなのか？こんにちは、ソフトウェアエンジニアの冨田です。
```

I made the following code but it fails to remove 'Tech|':

```
text = re.sub(r'\d{4}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}(?=.*Tech|)', '', text)
```

I would appreciate your kind suggestions.

Comment: `|` is a meta-character in regex, I think you should escape it?

Comment: You don't have to use a lookahead, just match it and escape the pipe `\d{4}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}.*?\bTech\|` See https://regexr.com/7g0pj

Comment: @Thefourthbird thank you for the suggestion. I tried it out but neither the digits nor the 'Tech|' was removed this time...

Comment: @Timus thank you. I should have added '\' before it.

Comment: @JulietaMatevosyan See https://ideone.com/BKtIoG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Match `Tech|` instead of asserting it to the right, escape the pipe to match it literally, and use a non greedy `.*?` to match the first occurrence of `Tech|`

The word boundary `\b` prevents a partial word match.

```
import re
 
s = "dbt とは何をするツールなのか？2022.02.09data build tool|dbt|Tech|こんにちは、ソフトウェアエンジニアの冨田です。"
pattern = r"\d{4}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}.*?\bTech\|"
print(re.sub(pattern, '', s))
```

Output

```
dbt とは何をするツールなのか？こんにちは、ソフトウェアエンジニアの冨田です。
```

See a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/BKtIoG).

Answer (score 1):

`Tech|` is being used as a delimiter so that what is matched is between the date
and the delimiter. This runs the risk, if `Tech|` is not found or this literal could possibly change.
Note that any imperfection or missing part of the delimiter will cause
the match to go through all the Unicode chars to find the next delimiter
wiping them out as well.

If this is a 1-off then no problem.
It appears that ASCII characters following the date may be a better delimiter.
An alternative is one with an ASCII delimiter following the date.

```
\d+\.\d+\.\d+(?:\s*[\x21-\x7e]+)*\s?
```

code

```
text = re.sub(r'\d+\.\d+\.\d+(?:\s*[\x21-\x7e]+)*\s?', '', text)
```

You could also keep the `Tech|` delimiter but replace the `.*?` with
ASCII and white space only so as not overshoot in case of a change.

```
\d+\.\d+\.\d+(?:\s*[\x21-\x7e]+)*?\s*Tech\|
```